# How to get entity or class name with hibernate Criteria object

Tags: hibernate

Suppose i have  Criteria object as criteria. now how can i get the name of entity or class associated with this criteria object.

I understand that the crtieria object would have been created some thing like this at some place in code:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
```

Now if i recieve this criteria object and want to know the "persistentClass" entity, what is the simple way to get it?

thanks

Comment: I haven't found any way in the javadoc. Wrap the Criteria and its root class in a custom object, and pass this object instead of just the Criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
  CriteriaImpl impl = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
  String className = impl.getEntityOrClassName();

  if (className.equals(GenomicSequence.class.getName()))
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(BrcConstants.FAMILY_PARTITION, familyName));
  else
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("genomicSequence.family", familyName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution but still,

Create criteria with an alias,

```
createCriteria(String associationPath, String alias)
```

keep the mapping of alias and associatedPath somewhere, may be in a property file or Map which can be accessed from which ever class you want to know "persistentClass".

Then use **getAlias()** method  to get the alias, and look up in your map/property file to get the persistentClass.